# Is there any way to transform strings into compileable/runnable code?

Tags: c++

For example, suppose we have a string like:

```
string x = "for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){cout << \"Hello World!\n\";}"
```

What is the simplest way to complete the following function definition:

```
void do_code(string x); /* given x that's valid c++ code, executes that code  as if it were written inside of the function body */
```

Comment: Compilers do it all the time.  But it does take a compiler to do it properly.

Comment: Unlike other languages (like python, ruby or javascript), this is not simple in C++.

Comment: This can be done in a single line in C++, I guess.

Comment: Have you seen these. [Self modifying code 1 @ SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786583/self-modifying-code-c), [Self modifying code 2 @ SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399003/does-the-c-standard-allow-for-self-modifying-code)

Comment: The "right" answer for this is probably "don't do that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard C++ libraries do not contain a C++ parser/compiler. This means that your only choice is to either find and link a C++ compiler library or to simply output your string as a file and launch the C++ compiler with a system call.

The first thing, linking to a C++ compiler, would actually be quite doable in something like Visual Studio for example, that does indeed have DLL libraries for compiling C++ and spitting out a new DLL that you could link at runtime.

The second thing, is pretty much what any IDE does. It saves your text-editor stuff into a C++ file, compile it by system-executing the compiler and run the output.

That said, there are many languages with build-in interpreter that would be more suitable for runtime code interpretation.

Comment: +1 - lots of solid points.  There are also interpreters for subsets of C++ - there are [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers) about those....

Answer (score 3):

Not directly as you're asking for C++ to be simultaneously compiled and interpreted.

But there is [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), which is a compiler framework and [API](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html).  That would allow you to take in this case a string containing valid C++, invoke the LLVM infrastructure and then afterwards use a LLVM-based just in time compiler as described at length [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/os-createcompilerllvm1/index.html?ca=dat).  Keep in mind you must also support the C++ library.  You should also have some mechanism to map variables into your interpreted C++ and take data back out.

A big but worthy undertaking, seems like someone might have done something like this already, and maybe [Cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) is just that.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the Dynamic Linking Loader (POSIX only)

This has been tested in Linux and OSX.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<dlfcn.h>

void do_code( std::string x ) {
  { std::ofstream s("temp.cc");
    s << "#include<iostream>\nextern \"C\" void f(){" << x << '}'; }
  std::system( "g++ temp.cc -shared -fPIC -otemp.o" );
  auto h = dlopen( "./temp.o", RTLD_LAZY );
  reinterpret_cast< void(*)() >( dlsym( h, "f" ) )();
  dlclose( h );
}

int main() {
  std::string x = "for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){std::cout << \"Hello World!\\n\";}";
  do_code( x );
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFfS8MwFMXf@ymu8WGpXae@rt1A5oPCHkQEUQqlJmkbyJLSZNJR@tWtt38c8yUhJ@ee380Nq6qwYKzvr6Vm6shFnFtXi@yw9c4KClIXFwKzjiv5daFwlTO9Kree920kB25SZriggMb1eqqHBnxoPYB2Us0MAkuJE4dqxRjxI7wHsBDHQM7h0swtJVo0TtQaErJLCIyonPotGfzNsCy6RQQdhkzgk8VkCqQIApgZENoyqwWHMH953kFoRt0QGNnZ0RkoYQNcmUpoLF3dzoYlvL7tH9P9w@fH5K2F1NhNVQuXssy6eGyI3vjUhy3FBHtCdrkEkmM6oDxUccWUsTiackjpPM/DFDhkUtNpPP9HtsFqU9PBI/FwF@EWw/2wB4HfjmZmjm54fEKehFIG3k2t@FWS6IREHRmhf//RjNC@/2G5ygrbh4qrXw) You'll need to compile with the `-ldl` parameter to link `libdl.a`. Don't copy-paste this into production code as this has no error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
system("echo \"#include <iostream> \nint main() { for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){std::cout << i << std::endl;} }\" >temp.cc; g++ -o temp temp.cc && ./temp");
```

Comment: I think the original question has an implication of non-portability about it :)